# Coin Flip with Numpy confusion

Tags: python, numpy, coin-flipping

I'm in the process of learning python and numpy, etc. I'm working on a coding a coin flip, however I'm confused about the code somewhat. I went back through the lesson, but don't see where it explains 
why total_sums is equal to 2 in the following code.

```
tests = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(int(1e6), 3), p=[0.6, 0.4])
test_sums = tests.sum(axis=1)
(test_sums == 2).mean()
```

I was able to get the above code correct, except for the test_sums == 2, which I was stuck for a long time.

The purpose of the code is to see when you flip a coin three times, what is the probability that it will land on heads once. In this case, heads is 0 and tails is 1. Can someone enlighten me as to what I missed? Thank you

Comment: Since heads is 0 and tails is 1, the sum of 3 trials is 2 if it lands on heads once (and tails twice).

Comment: What do you think it should be, and why?

Comment: OK, that makes sense. For some reason I was thinking 1, because in my head I was thinking two coin flips instead of three. So because I was wrong, I was thinking I was completely misunderstanding was == 2 was referring to.Thank you both for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You have three flips in each trial.  You're checking to see how often you get exactly one head.  1 head implies, ipso facto, 2 tails.  Testing for 2 tails is exactly the same as testing for 1 head.

`test_sums == 2` goes through the series of flips, yieliding `True` (1) or `False` (0) for each trial, depending on whether the three flips summed to `2`.  This expression returns a series of Boolean values, marking each desired trial -- 1 head`with a`1`.

For example, let's consider a set of only 5 trials (your code does one million) of 3 flips each, with results:

```
tests = [ [0 1 0] [1 1 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 1] [0 0 0] ]
```

We will now get

```
test_sums = [ 1 2 0 1 0 ]
```

`(test_sums == 2)` is a temporary variable, looking like this:

```
[ False True False True False ]
```

Which encodes as

```
[ 0 1 0 1 0 ]
```

... and the mean of this series is `0.4`, which will appear as the desired probability.

The arithmetic mean of this series is the probability of a `1` in that series -- to wit, the probability of getting exactly 1 head in 3 flips, in that trial series.

Does that clear it up?